# spring-context and spring-web 4.2.4.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-context

Why I need to include `spring-context` in my new `spring boot` project to work ?

I have this in my `pom.xml`

```
 <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

I can see inside spring-web dependency, the dependency spring-context

if I remove spring-context from my pom.xml, the application does not run.

Below is the error I get :

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nameOfController'
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: when I run application: 

Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nameOfController'

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the spring-context to be provided with spring-web or really that it just depends on it? You might want to do yourself a favor and use the spring boot starter artefacts that actually come with all required dependencies and don't mark any of them as "provided".

In your case, it would be spring-boot-starter-web.

Answer (score 0):

When we go through the compile dependencies of `spring-web` , then `spring-context` is not included in the **latest-version**.

https://frontbackend.com/maven/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/5.2.6.RELEASE

**Though it was present in the previous versions.**

https://frontbackend.com/maven/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/4.3.20.RELEASE

Since, I cannot see the specific version that you'r adding to your pom.xml file, I am assuming it is getting the latest version, where the dependency of `spring-context` is not included in `spring-web`.

Also, the error stack trace that you have provided is **very less and generic in nature**, so it becomes difficult to debug your problem further, though I think it is a problem with version.

You can give the specific version in this way :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```